# Adding a formula to a cell from VBA code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to put in a specific cell a formula via VBA Code.

This is my formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("SK-",IF(A5+1<1000,IF(A5+1>=10,CONCATENATE("0",A5+1),CONCATENATE("00",A5+1)),A5+1),"-",RIGHT(J8,LEN(J8)-2))
```

And i want to add the formula to a cell, but the error 1004 appears when I execute the code.

I'm trying this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("J6").Formula = "=CONCATENATE('SK-',IF(A5+1<1000,IF(A5+1>=10,CONCATENATE('0',A5+1),CONCATENATE('00',A5+1)),A5+1),'-',RIGHT(J8,LEN(J8)-2))"
```

Any question post on comments!

Comment: Your issue is with the formula itself rather than your method of putting it in. If you try `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J6").Formula = "=TODAY()"` there's no problem. So likely you have mis-spelt something or missed a bracket etc.

Comment: @TimEdwards The formula it's ok, if your tests the formula directly on the sheet the formula works correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work on my machine - I think it's the `'` characters....

Comment: I've just noticed you've swapped your double quotes for single quotes. Surely you just need to put two double quotes in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J6").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""SK-"",IF(A5+1<1000,IF(A5+1>=10,CONCATENATE(""0"",A5+1),CONCATENATE(""00"",A5+1)),A5+1),""-"",RIGHT(J8,LEN(J8)-2))"`

Comment: Oh, now the code works, I didn't know you could do that! Thanks for your support!